# How to extract a string from double square brackets in Pig

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I am trying to extract string from my input data which is like:
`I love [[cricket]]. Let's play it at [[16:00]].`

I want the output to be just : `cricket, 16:00`

I have tried multiple regex like:

```
'(?<=\[\[).*?(?=\]\])',  
'\\[\\[(.*?)\\]\\]',  
'\[\[(.*?)\]\]',  
'[[([^>]*?)]]'.

grunt> Register '/usr/local/pig/lib/piggybank.jar';
grunt> Define Xpath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath();
grunt> page = Load 'hdfs://master:9000/IP/Wikipedia-20181215070630.xml'            using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('page') as (x : chararray);
link = Foreach page Generate Flatten(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x, '(?<=\[\[).*?(?=\]\])'));
```

Whenever my regex has '[', pig throws below error message:

```
<line 1, column 64>  Unexpected character '['
2018-12-22 04:41:24,535 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 1, column 64>  Unexpected character '['.
```

And when I tried other above mentioned regex, I get blank output.

Comment: Try `\[\[([^]]+)\]\]`

Comment: Still get the same error of unexpected character '['